# Python looping: idiomatically comparing successive items in a list

Tags: loops, iterator, python

I need to loop over a list of objects, comparing them like this: 0 vs. 1, 1 vs. 2, 2 vs. 3, etc. (I'm using pysvn to extract a list of diffs.) I wound up just looping over an index, but I keep wondering if there's some way to do it which is more closely idiomatic. It's Python; shouldn't I be using iterators in some clever way? Simply looping over the index seems pretty clear, but I wonder if there's a more expressive or concise way to do it.

```
for revindex in xrange(len(dm_revisions) - 1):
    summary = \
        svn.diff_summarize(svn_path,
                          revision1=dm_revisions[revindex],
                          revision2 = dm_revisions[revindex+1])
```

Comment: Personally, I feel that there may actually exist more clever ways to do this, but looping over the index is the clearest way to do it.

Comment: +1 for good description leading to my finding the solution, too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is called a sliding window. There's an [example in the `itertools` documentation](http://www.python.org/doc/2.3.5/lib/itertools-example.html) that does it. Here's the code:

```
from itertools import islice

def window(seq, n=2):
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result    
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result
```

What that, you can say this:

```
for r1, r2 in window(dm_revisions):
    summary = svn.diff_summarize(svn_path, revision1=r1, revision2=r2)
```

Of course you only care about the case where n=2, so you can get away with something much simpler:

```
def adjacent_pairs(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    a = it.next()
    for b in it:
        yield a, b
        a = b

for r1, r2 in adjacent_pairs(dm_revisions):
    summary = svn.diff_summarize(svn_path, revision1=r1, revision2=r2)
```

Comment: I see that the newer itertools documentation has a 'pairwise' function in the Recipes section ( http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html ). That seems like it would do the same thing, yes?

Comment: Yes. *(Thank goodness we have this 15-character limit. Otherwise I could just say "yes" in response to a yes-or-no question.)*

Comment: Great. That works and is, I think, more clear. I can give the revisions informative names so people know what's being used further down in the script. I appreciate seeing it all spelled out, too, even if I did wind up using "tee" and "izip".

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably do:

```
import itertools
for rev1, rev2 in zip(dm_revisions, itertools.islice(dm_revisions, 1, None)):
    summary = svn.diff_sumeraize(svn_python, revision1=rev, revision2=rev2)
```

Something similarly cleverer and not touching the iterators themselves could probably be done using

Comment: This was the first thing that popped into my mind, it being the more functional approach. Effectively, you're zipping the list with "the rest of" itself (resulting in v1,v2,v2,v3,v3...) and then taking pairs of two out of the resulting list (v1,v2)(v2,v3)(v3,v4)...

Comment: Makes sense, and seems quite concise. How about using izip, as described here: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html ?

Answer (score 3):

So many complex solutions posted, why not keep it simple?

```
myList = range(5)

for idx, item1 in enumerate(myList[:-1]):
    item2 = L[idx + 1]
    print item1, item2

>>> 
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the previous value in a variable. Initialize the variable with a value you're not likely to find in the sequence you're handling, so you can know if you're at the first element. Compare the old value to the current value.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like an interesting alternative way to do it--not quite as pythonic as creating a fancy pairwise iterator, though :)

Comment: Actually, a fancy pairwise iterator would be more Haskellish/Lispish, though it would work in Python.

Comment: Interesting; guess I've got more to learn about all three types of expression.

Answer (score -1):

Reduce can be used for this purpose, if you take care to *leave a copy of the current item in the result of the reducing function*.

```
def diff_summarize(revisionList, nextRevision):
    '''helper function (adaptor) for using svn.diff_summarize with reduce'''
    if revisionList:
        # remove the previously tacked on item
        r1 = revisionList.pop()
        revisionList.append(svn.diff_summarize(
            svn_path, revision1=r1, revision2=nextRevision))
    # tack the current item onto the end of the list for use in next iteration
    revisionList.append(nextRevision)
    return revisionList

summaries = reduce(diff_summarize, dm_revisions, [])
```

**EDIT:** Yes, but nobody said the result of the function in `reduce` has to be scalar. I changed my example to use a list. Basically, the last element is allways the previous revision (except on first pass), with all preceding elements being the results of the `svn.diff_summarize` call. This way, you get a list of results as your final output...

**EDIT2:** Yep, the code really was broken. I have here a workable dummy:

```
>>> def compare(lst, nxt):
...    if lst:
...       prev = lst.pop()
...       lst.append((prev, nxt))
...    lst.append(nxt)
...    return lst
...
>>> reduce(compare, "abcdefg", [])
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'e'), ('e', 'f'), ('f', 'g'), 'g']
```

This was tested in the shell, as you can see. You will want to replace `(prev, nxt)` in the `lst.append` call of `compare` to actually append the summary of the call to `svn.diff_summarize`.

```
>>> help(reduce)
Help on built-in function reduce in module __builtin__:

reduce(...)
    reduce(function, sequence[, initial]) -> value

    Apply a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of a sequence,
    from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.
    For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates
    ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5).  If initial is present, it is placed before the items
    of the sequence in the calculation, and serves as a default when the
    sequence is empty.
```

Comment: No, reduce applies the function to each element in the sequence and *the accumulated reduced value so far*, rather than applying it to each element and its predecessor.

Comment: I believe that the OP simply wants to compare successive elements. What reduce does is operate on the first two elements, takes the result of that, and performs the operation with the result and the next element, and repeats this until no elements are left.

Comment: Sure, but that is only marginally different - you are still comparing data from one iteration to the data from the next iteration. See updated code.

Comment: That code is pretty broken, looks like. You *can* use reduce for this: http://pastie.org/798394 but I wouldn't recommend it. It seems unnecessarily opaque.