# How to get indexed entries from a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list:

```
a=['a1','a2','a3','a4']
```

and want to get adjacent list entries in following order such as

```
a1 a2
a2 a3
a3 a4
```

I tried following but its not working.

```
for i,b in enumerate(a):
    w1=i[i]
    w2=i[i+1]
    print w1,w2
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, because the other question asked for an iterator in a more complex scenario. This question allows the simple solution `for window in zip(a, a[1:])`.

Comment: There is also this: [Python looping: idiomatically comparing successive items in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2152640) and [Python split string in moving window](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7636004) many more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different alternatives:

Loop over indices up to the length minus 1:

```
for i in xrange(len(a) - 1):
    print a[i:i+2]
```

or zip together the list and a slice of the list past the first index:

```
for window in zip(a, a[1:]):
    print window
```

or zip together the list plus an iterator over the list, advanced one step:

```
a_iter = iter(a)
next(a_iter)
for window in zip(a, a_iter):
    print window
```

Comment: one side Q if don't mind. Can we use tuple and a list together like:
`for i,j in zip((a,a[1:]),l):`

Comment: No, but you can *nest* them: `zip(zip(a, a[1:]), l)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution

```
def get_entries(a, size):
    return [a[i:i+size] for i in range(len(a) - (size - 1))]

a = ['a1','a2','a3','a4']
for i in range(1, 5):
    print get_entries(a, i)
```

**Output**

```
[['a1'], ['a2'], ['a3'], ['a4']]
[['a1', 'a2'], ['a2', 'a3'], ['a3', 'a4']]
[['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], ['a2', 'a3', 'a4']]
[['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[(a[i],a[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(a) - 1)]
```

Your code contains the symbol

```
i[i]
```

Probably a typo, which will not execute because in your code i is an integer. A slight modification makes the original code work:

```
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    w1=a[i]
    w2=a[i+1]
    print w1,w2
```

Comment: are you helping OP solve problem or sniping?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: ?? I tested it, it works fine. In [2]: [(a[i],a[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(a) - 1)]
Out[2]: [('a1', 'a2'), ('a2', 'a3'), ('a3', 'a4')]

Comment: maybe i misunderstood. what do you mean by "is a syntax error"?

Comment: I was letting op know why their code would not run. i[i] does not work if i is an integer.

Comment: OK, what you just explained to me is missing from your answer. If you included that explanation, I'd see this as a legit answer.